# How to prevent duplication of bar chart in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport

I've tried to use chart in `iReport` for the first time. I've used a bar chart and anytime I preview the chart I see plenty of them, iIthink about 6. I only need a single one is there anything that I didn't do?
I have a query like this :

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_message, `status`, DATE_FORMAT(date_created,'%M') AS `month` FROM message WHERE YEAR(date_created)=$P{year} GROUP BY `status`, MONTH(date_created) ORDER BY `status` DESC
```

and I have a result like

```
|total message | status | month       |
|1             | FAILED | January     |
|10            | SENT   | Febuary     |
|11            | SENT   | March       |
|123           | SENT   | April       |
|156           | FAILED | May         |
 ..........
```

up to december.

My serie expression is set to `${Status}`
categorie expression is `${month}`
value expression is `${total_message}`

Can somebody help me? thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide any code, but I have a guess: you have put the chart in the details band, and you are printing it for each record in your DataSource. Put the chart in a non-repeatable band.